# resize iScroll 4 to fit 100% on any device

Tags: javascript, resize, iscroll, iscroll4

I'm trying to resize my wrapper, so when viewed on iPhone, iPad or computer 100% of my site is in view. I have placed pictures in my scroller using the `<ul>` and `<il>` methods. 
At the moment everything is in view on my computer, but on iPhone the pictures are getting cut off. It's letting me scroll horizontally and vertically my pictures, but need to resize the wrapper so my pictures are smaller. 
Any help would be amazing. Cheers in advance

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide any codes, so these maybe help you:

1. Set proper ***width/height*** to your wrapper when browser resizes and window.onload. Because we don't know device is in landscape or portrait mode until **window.onload**. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15840822/1344509) better explained how to get resized browser width/height.
2. Check your images *width/height*. Maybe images' dimensions wider than **wrapper**. You can set *width/height* to image in percent.
3. And don't forget refresh iScroll when browser resizes. You can do it like that:

   `setTimeout(function(){myScroller.refresh()}, 400); // browser need time to rotate`